# How can I inform moderators to rethink about their decision?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I asked few questions on English Language Learners, and one of them is marked as a *duplicate*:

[Are "present continuous" and "be going to" interchangeable?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/116516/are-present-continuous-and-be-going-to-interchangeable)

I believe the question is not duplicate, but maybe the moderators were mislead by the comments.

So, is there any way to ask them to take another look at the question?

Can you help me to figure out why the question consider *duplicate*, please?

Comment: If you've read the answers to the question that is the suggested duplicate, and you feel that your question hasn't been answered, edit your question to explain why the proposed duplicate isn't helpful.  There is a lot of discussion in the comments, and it would be good to pull that into your question and distinguish it from the proposed duplicate.

Comment: The mods did not close the question as a duplicate, it was closed by the following users:  Andrew, Glorfindel, Nathan Tuggy, LMS, Brian Tompsett - 汤莱恩. So best modify your post and ask "Why do **some users** believe my question was a duplicate?". and, it's not enough to say you don't think it is a duplicate, you have to convince the rest of us that you are right :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA you can read it, and let me know if you think it is duplicate.

Comment: You really should modify the title for the reason I  stated in the comment above. And the answer to your question (?) is : It's not a duplicate.